# Retrieving ID from SQL Server 2008 table to asp.net site and then inserting the ID into another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have this codes:

part of .cs file for Upload page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BtnImport1.Visible = false;
        Cancel.Visible = false;
}

private string ErrorMessage(string input)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return input;

     BtnImport1.Visible = false; 
     return "No value entered!";
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileNameOnServer = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
    string fileExt =
        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);

    if (fileUpload.PostedFile != null && fileExt == ".csv")
    {
        try
        {
           fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"));
           Label1.Text = "File name: " +
                          fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" +
                          fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>" +
                          "Content type: " +
                          fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Label1.Text = "Error saving <b>" + strFileNameOnServer + "</b><br>.  " + ex.Message;
        }
        BtnImport1.Visible = true;
        Cancel.Visible = true;
        fileUpload.Visible = false;
        btnUpload.Visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
        Label1.Text = "Error - a file name must be specified/only csv files are allowed";
        return;
     }        
}

protected void BtnImport1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"));
    string line;
    while ((line = Sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] tokens = line.Split(',');
        const string SQL = "INSERT INTO Attendance ([GuestID], [IC_No], [Grouping], [Remarks], [GuestName], [Class_Group], [Staff], [Attendance_Parents_Only], [Registration], [Event_ID] ) VALUES (@GuestID, @IC_No, @Grouping, @Remarks, @GuestName, @Class_Group, @Staff, @Attendance_Parents_Only, @Registration, @Event_ID)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestID", tokens[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC_No", tokens[1]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grouping", tokens[2]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", tokens[3]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuestName", tokens[4]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class_Group", tokens[5]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff", tokens[6]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance_Parents_Only", tokens[7]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registration", tokens[8]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", tokens[9]);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        con.Close();
     }
     Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
  }
```

So I want to get the `EventID` from SQL Server 2008 table called `Event`, and then inserting it into another table called `Attendance` as stated at `BtnImport1_Click`. There are the `EventID` and `EventName` columns in the table, called `Event`. I have queried string the `EventName` from the a ListBox in another .cs page. The query string stores the `EventName`:

```
protected void up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        //if the item is selected in the listboxs
        if (li.Selected)
        {
           Response.Redirect("Upload.aspx?ename=" + this.ListBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Now, I do not know how to match the stored `EventName` with the `EventID` and also inserting the `EventID` into the `Event` table, together with the other information at `BtnImport1_Click`.

Please help, I've been cracking my head since a few days already =/

Comment: Just a note: the database you're using is called **SQL Server 2008** - the "Management" thingie is called SQL Server Management Studio - but that's **not** the database product itself - it's a GUI frontend to work with the database. So it's a **SQL Server** table - not a SQL Server Management table - you're dealing with here....

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table `Event` with two columns `EventID` and `EventName`, and you do have the `EventName`, then you can use a query like

```
SELECT EventID
FROM dbo.Event
WHERE EventName = @EventName
```

in your code. Mind you: this will only reliably work if all event names are unique - if you happen to have two events by the same name, you cannot distinguish these two anymore.....

So really: you shouldn't be using / storing the event name - you should have the **EventID** at hand when you do work in your UI - the **ID** is the one thing that uniquely and clearly identifies an event.

So what you really need to do is change your application so that you have the **EventID** available when the user makes a choice in your ASP.NET UI. Most often, you can specify both a display value for the user (the event's name), as well as a **key value** that would be your EventID. When the user picks an event from your dropdown list, the user picks a name - but you'll be able to grab the **EventID** which is your key to your data.

**Update:** in order to get both `EventID` and `EventName` into your listbox, you need to use a class `Event` that contains both values. Fill that class from the database and bind it to the listbox, making `EventName` the DataTextField, and `EventID` the DataValueField. Then, the event name will be shown, but when the user selects an item, you can access the entire item - including it's `EventID`

Comment: so, how should I change it in order for the value to be displayed in the listview while the keyvalue is the EventID? I'm sorry for my ignorance, I just could'nt get it to work, or do you want to see all the codes that I did for the .cs pages?

Comment: can u show me an example of how to create this class? Because I don't really understand the technical details. Lets say I have a table called Event and columns EventName, EventID. In that class, what should I type to fill the class from database and bind it to the listbox?